# Need to open .ics calendar file in both Desktop & Mobile

Tags: mobile, calendar, desktop, ical4j

We used iCal4j to generate the .ics file in our website. We have a button in our event page which will download .ics file, when we open the downlaod .ics in desktop it is working as expected, but not in Mobile both Android & iOS.
Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Is this question about programming? Asking because this is a site for programming questions, and I don’t see how yours is one.

Comment: Require further detail on how it is not working on mobile, perhaps with samples.